# Duda punteros dobles y funciones

Tags: c

Tengo mi duda con respecto a la funcion cargar y los punteros dobles, me genera error en el momento de mostrar en pantalla no se si la variable no hace el paso por la direccion de la memoria.

No se lo que genera el error o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, lo hice con funciones como practica.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void cargar(char**,int);

int main(){

    int N = 3;
    int i;
    char **array;

    cargar(array,N);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

        printf("\n\nNOMBRE: %s\n ",array[i]);

    }

    free(array);

}

void cargar(char **array,int lon){

    int i,tam;
    char valor[10];

    array = (char**)malloc(lon*sizeof(char*));

    for(i=0;i<lon;i++){

        printf("Ingrese un nombre: ");
        scanf("%10[^\n]",valor);

        fflush(stdin);

        tam = strlen(valor);

        array[i] = (char*)malloc(tam*sizeof(char));
        if(*(array + i) == NULL){
            printf("No se pudo asignar");
            exit(-1);
        }
        strcpy(*(array + i),valor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

El problema que estás encontrando es un problema común: estás pasando un puntero por copia, lo que significa que el puntero `array` de la función `main` no es el mismo que el puntero `array` de la función `cargar`. Puedes verlo en este ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(char **puntero)
{
    printf( "dentro de f:\t&puntero es\t%p\n"
        "dentro de f:\tpuntero es\t%p\n",
        &puntero, puntero);
}

int main()
{
    char **puntero;
    printf( "en main:\t&puntero es\t%p\n"
        "en main:\tpuntero es\t%p\n",
        &puntero, puntero);

    f(puntero);

    char *otro_puntero;
    printf( "en main:\t&otro_puntero es\t%p\n"
        "en main:\totro_puntero es\t%p\n",
        &otro_puntero, otro_puntero);

    f(&otro_puntero);

    return 0;
}
```

Que produce la siguiente salida<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
> en main:      &puntero es         0x7ffd242409e8
> en main:      puntero es          (nil)
> dentro de f:  &puntero es         0x7ffd242409c8
> dentro de f:  puntero es          (nil)
> en main:      &otro_puntero es    0x7ffd242409e0
> en main:      otro_puntero es     0x7ffd24240ad0
> dentro de f:  &puntero es         0x7ffd242409c8
> dentro de f:  puntero es          0x7ffd242409e0
> ```

Observa que en `main` la dirección de `puntero` era `0x7ffd242409`**`e`**`8` mientras que en `f` la dirección es `0x7ffd242409`**`c`**`8`; esto significa que **no son el mismo puntero** y que los cambios que hagas dentro de `f` se quedarán en `f`.

Sin embargo con `otro_puntero` observamos que su dirección es `0x7ffd242409e0` y que al pasarlo a `f` se conserva. Por lo tanto tu código debería funcionar con esta corrección:

```
int main(){

    int N = 3;
    int i;
    char *array; // Un solo nivel de puntero

    cargar(&array,N);
//         ^ <--- Dirección al buffer

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

        printf("\n\nNOMBRE: %s\n ",array[i]);

    }

    free(array);

}
```

Pero eso es sólo parte del problema: aunque ahora pasas bien los datos a la función `carga` no estás rellenando bien los datos en dicha función. Si te fijas estás *sobrescribiendo* el puntero recibido:

```
void cargar(char **array,int lon){

    ...

    // Cambiamos el valor de 'array' al valor retornado por 'malloc'
    array = (char**)malloc(lon*sizeof(char*));

    ...
}
```

No quieres cambiar el puntero, quieres cambiar el lugar al que apunta:

```
void cargar(char **array,int lon){

    ...

//  v <--- Contenido de 'array'
    *array = (char*)malloc(lon*sizeof(char));
//            ^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//              |                  \    Dado que quieres una cadena de caracteres
//   quieres una cadena de          \__ debes reservar memoria para caracteres
//   caracteres, es decir un            no para punteros a caracteres.
//   char *

    ...
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Los valores de los punteros pueden cambiar en cada ejecución.

Comment: Hey! muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Realice el cambio como me indicastes y el error sigue ocurriendo no me muestra ningun elemento y se cierra el programa

Comment: Eso se debe a que tienes otro problema en la función `cargar`, pues reservas mal la memoria. Editaré la respuesta.